# Spring datasource :- Your network access was interrupted

Tags: java, spring, ms-access, spring-mvc, jdbc-odbc

I have created a Spring web application for reading ms access large database file. Sometime this file is repaired due to large size. Before compacting database file all open sessions are closed. After closing session and repairing database when we connect to database from spring web application then  i get the following error.

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
 SQL [select [DateTimeEntered],[GoodWeight],[MachineSpeed],[GradeCode],[RejectedWeight] 
 from [tblMachineProduction] where [DateTimeEntered] between ? and ? order by 
 [DateTimeEntered]]; [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Your network access was 
 interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again.; nested exception 
 is java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Your network access 
 was interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again.
```

How to hanlde this exception or how to reload/ initialize data source.

Spring code is here:-

```
<bean id="dataSource" scope="prototype" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>

</bean>
```